# Given a function of two variables, how can I define a 2nd function that is the integral of the 1st w.r.t. one of the variables?

Tags: numerical-integration

Given a function of two variables, how can I define a 2nd function that is the integral of the 1st w.r.t. one of the variables?

I have a function $f(x,y)$ and I want to do the integration like $\int^1_{-1} dy f(x,y)$ to obtain a 2nd function, say, $g(x)$. But when I try to do this with `NIntegrate`, the mathematica reports that the "the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values...".
So what commander should I use to take such a form integration?

Let's take an example. Let $f(x,y)=x^2y+xy^2$, and I want to do the integration $\int^1_0 x^2y+xy^2$. I try to do this by

```
NIntegrate[x^2y + xy^2,{x, 0, 1}]
```

Mathematica now reports that

> the integrand x^2y+xy^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values ...

Indeed, when x is taking a number, say, 0.5, $x^2y+xy^2=0.5y^2+0.25y$ and it is not a numerical values. But my question is, how to do the integration of this kind?

Comment: `Nintegrate[]` will not work if there are any hanging symbols in your integrand (it is an `N*[]` function, after all). You could define a function like `fint[x_] := (* stuff *)`, tho.

Comment: @J.M. I really thank you for your comment. But can you put it more clearly? I am sorry that I don't understand it very much.

Comment: `NIntegrate[Sin[x + y], {y, -1, 1}]` will not work because of the `y`. Is that clearer?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I realized it. But I am not clear that then how to do the integration.  What do you mean by defining a function fint[x_] := (* stuff *)?

Comment: It will be useful if you give a concrete example of what you are doing.  Otherwise people can only *guess* about what is going wrong.

Comment: @Jens I don't think the link answers my question. I think J.M. answered my question, but I don't get it clearly. What does the "stuff" mean in the bracket?

Comment: You'll have to write down an example for your function `f` first.

Comment: As @Jens noted, `(* stuff *)` is to be replaced with whatever you actually have, which you seem to have forgotten to supply in asking this question.

Comment: @Jens and Szabolcs,  I have given an example.

Comment: Then why are you not using `Integrate[]` if you want a symbolic solution?

Comment: @J.M., But in my case, the function $f(x,y)$ is not an analytical one. It is a numerical function generated by InterpolatingFunction.

Comment: Then you either replace `y` with a number (e.g. `With[{y = 2/3}, NIntegrate[x^2 y + x y^2, {x, 0, 1}]]`) or you accomplish nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this. I am assuming in your actual application `f` will require numerical integration, even though in this example it doesn't.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 y + x y^2
g[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[g[y], {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {y, g[x]}]
```

[image: plot]